# Group By in XSLT or preceding sibbling

Tags: xslt

This is xml I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message>
    <CarouselMap>
        <Panel>FLWPB</Panel>
        <Panel>FLWPB</Panel>
        <Panel>FLWBM</Panel>
        <Panel>ALPS</Panel>
        <Panel>MM</Panel>
        <Panel>ACUTE</Panel>
        <Panel>CD10B</Panel>
        <Panel>PNH</Panel>
        <Panel>FLWBM</Panel>
    </CarouselMap>
</Message>
```

I need to use

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Message/CarouselMap" group-by="Panel">
```

I need to put FLWPB, and FLWBM in the same group and the rest in separate group.  Something like this

```
        <Panel>FLWPB</Panel>
        <Panel>ALPS</Panel>
        <Panel>MM</Panel>
        <Panel>ACUTE</Panel>
        <Panel>CD10B</Panel>
        <Panel>PNH</Panel>
```

I can add a suffix to the end of each panel like

```
<Message>
    <CarouselMap>
        <Panel>FLWPB_AA</Panel>
        <Panel>FLWPB_AA</Panel>
        <Panel>FLWBM_AA</Panel>
        <Panel>ALPS_BB</Panel>
        <Panel>MM_CC</Panel>
        <Panel>ACUTE_DD</Panel>
        <Panel>CD10B_EE</Panel>
        <Panel>PNH_FF</Panel>
        <Panel>FLWBM_AA</Panel>
    </CarouselMap>
</Message>
```

and then use

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Message/CarouselMap" group-by="substring_after(Panel, '_')">
```

But I thought there might be a better way.  Can you please provide a hint or better solution?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question indicates you are able to manipulate the source data.  This being so, I would add a "grouping key" to each element thus:

```
<Message>
    <CarouselMap>
        <Panel key="FLW">FLWPB</Panel>
        <Panel key="FLW">FLWPB</Panel>
        <Panel key="FLW">FLWBM</Panel>
        <Panel key="ALPS">ALPS</Panel>
        <Panel key="MM">MM</Panel>
        <Panel key="ACUTE">ACUTE</Panel>
        <Panel key="CD10B">CD10B</Panel>
        <Panel key="PNH">PNH</Panel>
        <Panel key="FLW">FLWBM</Panel>
    </CarouselMap>
```

Now, using the following XSLT

```
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="/Message/CarouselMap">

    <xsl:for-each-group select="Panel" group-by="@key">
<Panel><xsl:value-of select="."/></Panel>
    </xsl:for-each-group>

  </xsl:template>
```

gives you the XML you asked for:

```
<Panel>FLWPB</Panel>
<Panel>ALPS</Panel>
<Panel>MM</Panel>
<Panel>ACUTE</Panel>
<Panel>CD10B</Panel>
<Panel>PNH</Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to put FLWPB, and FLWBM in the same group and the rest in
>   separate group.

I am assuming you actually want to put `FLWPB` and `FLWBM` in the same group and the rest in separate *groups* - one group for each distinct value.

That could be achieved by doing:

```
<xsl:template match="/Message">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="CarouselMap/Panel" group-by="if (. = 'FLWBM') then 'FLWPB' else .">
            <group>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

with no need to modify your original input.